# Laravel Scope by pivot data values

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Say I want to store various bits of data about customers, so I have two models linked by a pivot table, storing the customer's values for each datafield type on the pivot table:

```
Customer {
    public function datafields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Datafield')->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

and

```
Datafield {
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Customer')->withPivot('value');
    }
```

So my tables are customers, customer_datafield, datafields.

How can I set up a query scope in the customer to find all customers that have a value of x for a specfic datafield?

Something along the lines of

```
Customer {
    public function datafields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Datafield')->withPivot('value');
    }
    public function scopeSearch($query, $searchfor)
    {
        return $query->datafields()->pivot()
            ->where('value', $searchfor)
            ->where('datafield_id', 123);
    }
}
```

I've tried a few methods but not having any luck geting one to work. Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Eloquent way for a single fixed pivot field:

```
public function scopeDataValue($query, $search)
{
    $pivot = $this->datafields()->getTable();

    $query->whereHas('datafields', function ($q) use ($search, $pivot) {
        $q->where("{$pivot}.value", $search);
    });
}

// usage
Model::
```

This gives you more power and flexibility:

```
public function scopeDataValues($query, array $search, $bool = 'and')
{
    $pivot = $this->datafields()->getTable();

    $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($search, $pivot, $bool) {
        $q->where(function ($q) use ($search, $pivot, $bool) {
            foreach ($search as $field => $value)
            {
                $q->where("{$pivot}.{$field}", '=', $value, $bool);
            }
        });
    });
}

// usage
Model::dataValues(['value' => 'findMe', 'otherField' => 'findMeToo'])->get();

Model::dataValues(['value' => 'findMe', 'otherField' => 'orFindMe'], 'or')->get();
```

You might be tempted to use `where` with array of values instead of `foreach` in the second closure, however it might not work as expected, for fields won't be prefixed with table name.

---

Another solution is to use simple `join`:

```
public function scopeDataValue($query, $search)
{
    $pivot = $this->datafields()->getTable();

    // first get array of already joined table
    $base = $query->getQuery();
    $joins = array_fetch((array) $base->joins, 'table');

    $foreignKey = $this->categories()->getForeignKey();

    // if table has not been joined, let's do it
    if ( ! in_array($pivot, $joins))
    {
        $query->join($pivot, $this->getQualifiedKeyName(), '=', $foreignKey);
    }

    $query->where("{$pivot}.correct", $search);
}

// usage
Model::dataValue(2)->take(..)->where(..)->dataValue(5)->get();
```

You can alter it the same way as 2nd example above.

Answer (score 3):

Note:  on Laravel 5  you can simply use this:

```
$query->wherePivot('pivotcolumn','=', $search);
```

Comment: i seem to get an error using this approach. `return $query->wherePivot('status', '=', 'planned');` this line returns column 'pivot' not found.

Comment: @Gokigooooks wherePivot  is only allowed on belongsTomany relations  so be that your  $query is an instance of b2m.

Comment: hey i do have a belongsToMany relationship.. i resorted to using a `where('model.relationmodel','=','planned)` im glad laravel has many options :) thanks

Comment: I'm using this on a BelongsToMany query in laravel 4.2. Doesn't need to be Laravel 5.