# How to use wherePivot method in a scope?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have two models with a pivot.

```
Domain
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project')->withPivot('is_live');
    }
}

Project
{
    public function domains()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Domain')->withPivot('is_live');
    }
}
```

Then I try to create the scope "Domains which have Projects and is_live = true" like that [Laravel Scope by pivot data values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073924/laravel-scope-by-pivot-data-values)

```
public function scopeHasLiveProjects($query)
{
    $pivotTable = $this->projects()->getTable();
    return $query->whereHas('projects', function ($q) use ($pivotTable) {
            $q->where($pivotTable . '.is_live', true);
    });
}
```

But how I can use eloquent method ***wherePivot***('is_live', '=', true) in the scope? Is it possible?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function scopeHasLiveProjects($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('projects', function ($q) {
            $q->where('is_live', true);
    });
}
```

should do the needed

Comment: It's wrong solution, becouse 'is_live' is  field of the pivot table.

Comment: belongsToMany realtion table should be project_id, domain_id, is_live.
And when you choosing projects of domain where pivot is_live == true,  

return $query->whereHas('projects', function ($q) {
            $q->wherePivot('is_live', true);
    });

should be right i think

Comment: Great! Your first solution works!!!
function ($q) { $q->where('is_live', true); }); **not** function ($q) {  q->wherePivot('is_live', true); });