# How to make belongsToMany relation respect global scopes defined inside pivot model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many, global-scope

Lets say I have a User, Roles and User_Role table. I have a custom pivot model for my User_Role table. In a User model I have a relation like this

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'User_Role')
        ->using(UserRole::class);
}
```

I have a global scope inside UserRole model which is not included in this relation. I could use `wherePivot()` and copy the scope but I was wondering is that necessary ?
**Is there a way for a BelongsToMany relation to respect global scopes defined inside Pivot model**

Comment: I suppose the wherePivot() would be the best alternative here.

Check this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073924/laravel-scope-by-pivot-data-values